# Calculate product between sets, keeping only products without repeated items

Tags: python, set, cartesian-product

I have a list of sets similar as `[{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}]`, and I need to calculate the product between these sets but keeping only the solutions that **don't heave repeated numbers**. I found a solution using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but this still computes *all* the products, I was wondering if there was a built-in method that yields immediately what I want (or if you have a suggestion to manipulate the data structure to accelerate the computation time is well accepted).

My solution:

```
from itertools import product

def pick(sets):
    for p in product(*sets):
        if len(set(p)) == len(p):
            yield p
```

Which leads to the desired output:

```
>>> x = [{i, i+1} for i in range(5)]
>>> for p in pick(x):
...     print(p)
...
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 5)
(0, 1, 2, 4, 5)
(0, 1, 3, 4, 5)
(0, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def pick(sets, excluding=frozenset()):
    if not sets:
        yield ()
        return
    for x in sets[0] - excluding:
        for rest in pick(sets[1:], excluding | {x}):
            yield (x,) + rest
```

Comment: I would suggest `def pick(sets, excluding=frozenset()):`.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple. Do you think an iterative approach is feasible? I see that itertools.product is defined without recursion.